# SSH always refuses first connection attempt

Tags: ssh, aix, putty

There's an AIX box where I work and so I've not got any root access to it. When I connect to it using telnet I can get on fine. When I connect to it using SSH if I put in my correct password on the first attempt the connection gets closed.

However, if I get the password wrong on the first attempt but correct on the second it lets me on. (Using a public/private key pair also works OK.)

Any ideas what might be happening? Other users around me don't appear to have the same issue and can log on fine. We're all using the latest version of puTTY. I've even tried using my colleagues PCs in case it was a PuTTY set up thing but I still get the issue.

My debug options are limited as I can't get root access to the box but I'm hoping someone might be aware of a setting or something that I might be able to investigate? Googling has turned up nothing and I can't find anything in the SSH parameters I've read.

**Update**

Here is the output from the putty.log file when I put the correct password in first time:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2015.04.20 11:47:52 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Event Log: Writing new session log (SSH raw data mode) to file: putty.log
Event Log: Looking up host "helga-2"
Event Log: Connecting to 10.86.3.8 port 22
Incoming raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  53 53 48 2d 32 2e 30 2d 4f 70 65 6e 53 53 48 5f  SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_
  00000010  33 2e 38 70 31 0a                                3.8p1.
Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_3.8p1
Event Log: We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2
Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.64
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  53 53 48 2d 32 2e 30 2d 50 75 54 54 59 5f 52 65  SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Re
  00000010  6c 65 61 73 65 5f 30 2e 36 34 0d 0a              lease_0.64..
Outgoing packet #0x0, type 20 / 0x14 (SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT)
  00000000  be 09 c1 eb ea 56 02 74 53 bf df 22 80 40 bd 3a  .....V.tS..".@.:
<snip>
  00000280  6c 69 62 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  lib.............
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  00 00 02 9c 0a 14 be 09 c1 eb ea 56 02 74 53 bf  ...........V.tS.
<snip>
  00000290  00 00 00 00 00 00 ab f2 f3 af 2f 02 d8 9d 19 18  ........../.....
Incoming raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  00 00 02 5c 07 14 ad 46 a2 99 28 a9 b0 34 a5 fe  ...\...F..(..4..
<snip>
  00000250  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
Incoming packet #0x0, type 20 / 0x14 (SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT)
  00000000  ad 46 a2 99 28 a9 b0 34 a5 fe c7 55 46 75 06 61  .F..(..4...UFu.a
<snip>
  00000250  00 00 00                                         ...
Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Outgoing packet #0x1, type 30 / 0x1e (SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST)
  00000000  00 00 08 00                                      ....
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  00 00 00 0c 06 1e 00 00 08 00 03 af f5 4b 2f 70  .............K/p
Incoming raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  00 00 01 a4 0a 1f 00 00 01 8f 66 9b a3 ed 66 1f  ..........f...f.
<snip>
  000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........
Incoming packet #0x1, type 31 / 0x1f (SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP)
  00000000  00 00 01 8f 66 9b a3 ed 66 1f 22 6a 09 0b e5 64  ....f...f."j...d
<snip>
  00000190  2a f6 ab 00 00 00 01 02                          *.......
Event Log: Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
Outgoing packet #0x2, type 32 / 0x20 (SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT)
  00000000  00 00 01 8f 3d 66 c7 49 2b d3 b1 99 c9 82 62 19  ....=f.I+.....b.
  00000010  30 34 a2 04 6f 1a de 84 72 a7 a5 82 72 e9 20 79  04..o...r...r. y
  00000020  17 f6 67 22 2d 4d cf 4f cd 77 61 da 6e 30 00 36  ..g"-M.O.wa.n0.6
  00000030  e8 08 4b 6a a5 4e 6c 3a 9d 9b d1 65 b6 f0 59 18  ..Kj.Nl:...e..Y.
  00000040  1d 3e fa 3f ca c4 34 75 df 22 da 6d 1d 61 88 46  .>.?..4u.".m.a.F
  00000050  b0 2e 53 97 f4 e0 a2 6d 1e e2 29 aa ac ff a5 a7  ..S....m..).....
  00000060  26 b6 70 ce a2 8e c0 33 5d 5c 38 64 9a 98 9e 48  &.p....3]\8d...H
  00000070  7b 83 71 fb f2 33 41 0e 63 a5 50 ef 30 ab cf 38  {.q..3A.c.P.0..8
  00000080  8f df e4 65 45 8d ed 26 b6 78 cd 9f 70 dd 36 06  ...eE..&.x..p.6.
  00000090  27 f4 b5 14 c1 9a 60 68 bb fb 3c 71 d0 53 b1 e3  '.....`h..<q.S..
  000000a0  3a 00 6c e0 41 d4 f0 8d 09 d6 53 c3 40 93 8b b8  :.l.A.....S.@...
  000000b0  4c 79 32 af 32 9d 60 2f 47 fa fb 32 b1 9b ad e4  Ly2.2.`/G..2....
  000000c0  09 4b b2 3d 3d f9 1d e2 d2 a6 6c 56 d2 5e 55 49  .K.==.....lV.^UI
  000000d0  74 be 14 c3 27 ba b5 6e bb c3 66 2a 1f 96 15 cd  t...'..n..f*....
  000000e0  64 5a 92 18 83 4e b3 39 ee 0b f0 fa 5e 1d 06 1b  dZ...N.9....^...
  000000f0  88 ef d1 41 9e d1 60 d8 df 9f e8 a7 1c 91 1d 6a  ...A..`........j
  00000100  c6 f1 fb 86 85 9c 1b 84 3b 99 51 ce 8c 5c 1c 9e  ........;.Q..\..
  00000110  de 47 a5 0f 82 c6 e9 85 31 5d 82 6a cf 1a 5e d1  .G......1].j..^.
  00000120  e6 ed 85 26 b6 6c 04 2a 6e 13 48 4a f0 54 b5 48  ...&.l.*n.HJ.T.H
  00000130  27 bd 9e 6d 63 9c e1 dd 52 ed 68 71 65 26 5f 7f  '..mc...R.hqe&_.
  00000140  73 06 e4 7b 8a 20 e7 1b 61 64 8c 5c 3d 3b cd 41  s..{. ..ad.\=;.A
  00000150  9b f0 93 c8 c1 b9 0c 67 c9 56 ae 13 2b 3a 88 de  .......g.V..+:..
  00000160  13 b5 93 52 dd 23 4c ff b7 05 58 52 5f 35 4d 62  ...R.#L...XR_5Mb
  00000170  9d 55 19 97 ac a7 09 3f c3 29 ec 7d e3 77 82 40  .U.....?.).}.w.@
  00000180  a4 94 86 87 2b f4 14 21 34 ef 9c d4 42 cf b5 c9  ....+..!4...B...
  00000190  fa 3a 46                                         .:F
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  00 00 01 9c 07 20 00 00 01 8f 3d 66 c7 49 2b d3  ..... ....=f.I+.
  00000010  b1 99 c9 82 62 19 30 34 a2 04 6f 1a de 84 72 a7  ....b.04..o...r.
  00000020  a5 82 72 e9 20 79 17 f6 67 22 2d 4d cf 4f cd 77  ..r. y..g"-M.O.w
  00000030  61 da 6e 30 00 36 e8 08 4b 6a a5 4e 6c 3a 9d 9b  a.n0.6..Kj.Nl:..
  00000040  d1 65 b6 f0 59 18 1d 3e fa 3f ca c4 34 75 df 22  .e..Y..>.?..4u."
  00000050  da 6d 1d 61 88 46 b0 2e 53 97 f4 e0 a2 6d 1e e2  .m.a.F..S....m..
  00000060  29 aa ac ff a5 a7 26 b6 70 ce a2 8e c0 33 5d 5c  ).....&.p....3]\
  00000070  38 64 9a 98 9e 48 7b 83 71 fb f2 33 41 0e 63 a5  8d...H{.q..3A.c.
  00000080  50 ef 30 ab cf 38 8f df e4 65 45 8d ed 26 b6 78  P.0..8...eE..&.x
  00000090  cd 9f 70 dd 36 06 27 f4 b5 14 c1 9a 60 68 bb fb  ..p.6.'.....`h..
  000000a0  3c 71 d0 53 b1 e3 3a 00 6c e0 41 d4 f0 8d 09 d6  <q.S..:.l.A.....
  000000b0  53 c3 40 93 8b b8 4c 79 32 af 32 9d 60 2f 47 fa  S.@...Ly2.2.`/G.
  000000c0  fb 32 b1 9b ad e4 09 4b b2 3d 3d f9 1d e2 d2 a6  .2.....K.==.....
  000000d0  6c 56 d2 5e 55 49 74 be 14 c3 27 ba b5 6e bb c3  lV.^UIt...'..n..
  000000e0  66 2a 1f 96 15 cd 64 5a 92 18 83 4e b3 39 ee 0b  f*....dZ...N.9..
  000000f0  f0 fa 5e 1d 06 1b 88 ef d1 41 9e d1 60 d8 df 9f  ..^......A..`...
  00000100  e8 a7 1c 91 1d 6a c6 f1 fb 86 85 9c 1b 84 3b 99  .....j........;.
  00000110  51 ce 8c 5c 1c 9e de 47 a5 0f 82 c6 e9 85 31 5d  Q..\...G......1]
  00000120  82 6a cf 1a 5e d1 e6 ed 85 26 b6 6c 04 2a 6e 13  .j..^....&.l.*n.
  00000130  48 4a f0 54 b5 48 27 bd 9e 6d 63 9c e1 dd 52 ed  HJ.T.H'..mc...R.
  00000140  68 71 65 26 5f 7f 73 06 e4 7b 8a 20 e7 1b 61 64  hqe&_.s..{. ..ad
  00000150  8c 5c 3d 3b cd 41 9b f0 93 c8 c1 b9 0c 67 c9 56  .\=;.A.......g.V
  00000160  ae 13 2b 3a 88 de 13 b5 93 52 dd 23 4c ff b7 05  ..+:.....R.#L...
  00000170  58 52 5f 35 4d 62 9d 55 19 97 ac a7 09 3f c3 29  XR_5Mb.U.....?.)
  00000180  ec 7d e3 77 82 40 a4 94 86 87 2b f4 14 21 34 ef  .}.w.@....+..!4.
  00000190  9c d4 42 cf b5 c9 fa 3a 46 19 af ca 94 6b 48 f7  ..B....:F....kH.
Incoming raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  00 00 02 cc 0b 21 00 00 00 95 00 00 00 07 73 73  .....!........ss
  00000010  68 2d 72 73 61 00 00 00 01 23 00 00 00 81 00 eb  h-rsa....#......
  00000020  16 73 e9 2d 43 25 8a 59 98 28 bb fa ca 59 c7 36  .s.-C%.Y.(...Y.6
  00000030  24 e4 b1 ec 5c 95 d7 0a 60 d1 62 49 07 6d c3 fa  $...\...`.bI.m..
  00000040  3e ca 59 21 36 ea f5 58 d7 ff ba ac 51 e1 e2 d1  >.Y!6..X....Q...
  00000050  65 c9 78 c4 ba 88 f7 82 44 e6 cc 0f 95 c5 ee 5b  e.x.....D......[
  00000060  aa 84 b7 a0 f1 7c 28 82 32 c6 30 e7 ed 43 cb 68  .....|(.2.0..C.h
  00000070  7f 13 2c 36 f8 9d 64 69 84 5c 36 d7 2b 5f 4d 0d  ..,6..di.\6.+_M.
  00000080  b1 7a dc b4 79 3b c9 52 98 4b cb c5 ce 82 4a d3  .z..y;.R.K....J.
  00000090  94 0c f5 52 61 d6 e8 8f 99 5a d8 31 3b 06 cb 00  ...Ra....Z.1;...
  000000a0  00 01 8f 29 38 71 23 01 da eb f3 f1 9b 8f b8 0e  ...)8q#.........
  000000b0  66 74 8e 85 8e c4 76 ce 3a 7c 81 2c 98 c9 d2 d1  ft....v.:|.,....
  000000c0  a0 49 1b 00 84 cd 3f d8 a7 45 f3 d4 d9 49 9c 68  .I....?..E...I.h
  000000d0  e4 a0 3d 40 f6 d4 48 10 82 0d 69 95 bb 00 27 b9  ..=@..H...i...'.
  000000e0  d2 83 25 01 75 4e 39 77 d0 60 6a f5 13 5e f9 9f  ..%.uN9w.`j..^..
  000000f0  40 41 a6 17 60 47 dd cc 6e ce 96 2c ef 9e bd 26  @A..`G..n..,...&
  00000100  74 ce dc 23 b8 f1 52 6b 11 01 ea 27 53 ae e6 6a  t..#..Rk...'S..j
  00000110  9e 28 91 9e e8 43 08 35 34 1f ef 05 0f f6 0f b2  .(...C.54.......
  00000120  81 0c 53 14 7f 33 47 bc ad 16 17 f9 1e 63 dd a8  ..S..3G......c..
  00000130  8d b7 3b a1 89 07 31 9d bd 5f 4a b1 49 1d 5f 6f  ..;...1.._J.I._o
  00000140  94 d1 96 b5 48 6f f6 87 87 e0 30 92 38 f0 44 9b  ....Ho....0.8.D.
  00000150  9c 9a 91 4c 5b 70 37 77 c9 0f 00 2e 7f 8c 60 00  ...L[p7w......`.
  00000160  e0 1d 28 8e ae a9 f6 ac 34 a8 cc c5 a2 aa 93 c1  ..(.....4.......
  00000170  b2 06 01 46 61 4f b6 86 0b 75 44 7b 2b 97 d5 8b  ...FaO...uD{+...
  00000180  c8 73 24 65 fe 20 bd 46 27 d6 59 ff d6 9d 61 5a  .s$e. .F'.Y...aZ
  00000190  0d 88 fe a9 98 f6 ec d2 65 25 e9 ba e7 11 e6 35  ........e%.....5
  000001a0  82 81 03 6d f7 45 f1 fd 73 f5 64 b5 66 86 65 c6  ...m.E..s.d.f.e.
  000001b0  26 20 dc f1 cb 0a 23 44 04 25 94 4d b9 aa 6b 6b  & ....#D.%.M..kk
  000001c0  36 d1 c0 f4 d4 a0 56 93 3a 9e 69 ae ea d3 80 ea  6.....V.:.i.....
  000001d0  66 56 92 e1 93 21 63 0b f6 1c fc e4 9e b0 90 ca  fV...!c.........
  000001e0  7d c6 90 0f e9 85 8e 54 db f2 13 68 d7 7e 0e 4c  }......T...h.~.L
  000001f0  9d 6a 85 8d 4e 77 b8 25 98 f4 8a 63 31 34 7c 1e  .j..Nw.%...c14|.
  00000200  91 15 14 f2 94 dc d2 24 f9 f7 66 79 b9 86 73 43  .......$..fy..sC
  00000210  b1 e1 13 08 78 bc a3 1a f6 53 48 cf c1 99 4e a5  ....x....SH...N.
  00000220  65 b6 ab b0 03 e6 28 d6 c4 7a 1f 26 cd a1 f3 e6  e.....(..z.&....
  00000230  15 a9 00 00 00 8f 00 00 00 07 73 73 68 2d 72 73  ..........ssh-rs
  00000240  61 00 00 00 80 c4 13 df 45 7f e4 5f 77 6e b0 39  a.......E.._wn.9
  00000250  c2 eb d6 88 2f 68 7f d0 5f 78 e6 9d 82 2d 5a a0  ..../h.._x...-Z.
  00000260  10 95 a5 4b 22 2c 94 4f 34 be 01 55 22 d1 65 aa  ...K",.O4..U".e.
  00000270  3b 4b c0 d9 39 27 67 db 0b 4b 6c 2b ee 3b a8 71  ;K..9'g..Kl+.;.q
  00000280  a8 2a 4b 65 d4 59 39 81 57 93 8e 53 e9 ba c5 e0  .*Ke.Y9.W..S....
  00000290  82 32 90 88 95 9f 3f 51 0f 01 a8 ca 21 64 e4 b1  .2....?Q....!d..
  000002a0  db da f2 31 f7 67 07 d1 2d 55 0d 87 28 ff 7c 5a  ...1.g..-U..(.|Z
  000002b0  d8 b7 ac 0d 05 01 fc 13 35 98 de 8d 14 c8 be 7c  ........5......|
  000002c0  e2 70 75 8c 22 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .pu."...........
  000002d0  00 00 00 0c 0a 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
Incoming packet #0x2, type 33 / 0x21 (SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY)
  00000000  00 00 00 95 00 00 00 07 73 73 68 2d 72 73 61 00  ........ssh-rsa.
  00000010  00 00 01 23 00 00 00 81 00 eb 16 73 e9 2d 43 25  ...#.......s.-C%
  00000020  8a 59 98 28 bb fa ca 59 c7 36 24 e4 b1 ec 5c 95  .Y.(...Y.6$...\.
  00000030  d7 0a 60 d1 62 49 07 6d c3 fa 3e ca 59 21 36 ea  ..`.bI.m..>.Y!6.
  00000040  f5 58 d7 ff ba ac 51 e1 e2 d1 65 c9 78 c4 ba 88  .X....Q...e.x...
  00000050  f7 82 44 e6 cc 0f 95 c5 ee 5b aa 84 b7 a0 f1 7c  ..D......[.....|
  00000060  28 82 32 c6 30 e7 ed 43 cb 68 7f 13 2c 36 f8 9d  (.2.0..C.h..,6..
  00000070  64 69 84 5c 36 d7 2b 5f 4d 0d b1 7a dc b4 79 3b  di.\6.+_M..z..y;
  00000080  c9 52 98 4b cb c5 ce 82 4a d3 94 0c f5 52 61 d6  .R.K....J....Ra.
  00000090  e8 8f 99 5a d8 31 3b 06 cb 00 00 01 8f 29 38 71  ...Z.1;......)8q
  000000a0  23 01 da eb f3 f1 9b 8f b8 0e 66 74 8e 85 8e c4  #.........ft....
  000000b0  76 ce 3a 7c 81 2c 98 c9 d2 d1 a0 49 1b 00 84 cd  v.:|.,.....I....
  000000c0  3f d8 a7 45 f3 d4 d9 49 9c 68 e4 a0 3d 40 f6 d4  ?..E...I.h..=@..
  000000d0  48 10 82 0d 69 95 bb 00 27 b9 d2 83 25 01 75 4e  H...i...'...%.uN
  000000e0  39 77 d0 60 6a f5 13 5e f9 9f 40 41 a6 17 60 47  9w.`j..^..@A..`G
  000000f0  dd cc 6e ce 96 2c ef 9e bd 26 74 ce dc 23 b8 f1  ..n..,...&t..#..
  00000100  52 6b 11 01 ea 27 53 ae e6 6a 9e 28 91 9e e8 43  Rk...'S..j.(...C
  00000110  08 35 34 1f ef 05 0f f6 0f b2 81 0c 53 14 7f 33  .54.........S..3
  00000120  47 bc ad 16 17 f9 1e 63 dd a8 8d b7 3b a1 89 07  G......c....;...
  00000130  31 9d bd 5f 4a b1 49 1d 5f 6f 94 d1 96 b5 48 6f  1.._J.I._o....Ho
  00000140  f6 87 87 e0 30 92 38 f0 44 9b 9c 9a 91 4c 5b 70  ....0.8.D....L[p
  00000150  37 77 c9 0f 00 2e 7f 8c 60 00 e0 1d 28 8e ae a9  7w......`...(...
  00000160  f6 ac 34 a8 cc c5 a2 aa 93 c1 b2 06 01 46 61 4f  ..4..........FaO
  00000170  b6 86 0b 75 44 7b 2b 97 d5 8b c8 73 24 65 fe 20  ...uD{+....s$e. 
  00000180  bd 46 27 d6 59 ff d6 9d 61 5a 0d 88 fe a9 98 f6  .F'.Y...aZ......
  00000190  ec d2 65 25 e9 ba e7 11 e6 35 82 81 03 6d f7 45  ..e%.....5...m.E
  000001a0  f1 fd 73 f5 64 b5 66 86 65 c6 26 20 dc f1 cb 0a  ..s.d.f.e.& ....
  000001b0  23 44 04 25 94 4d b9 aa 6b 6b 36 d1 c0 f4 d4 a0  #D.%.M..kk6.....
  000001c0  56 93 3a 9e 69 ae ea d3 80 ea 66 56 92 e1 93 21  V.:.i.....fV...!
  000001d0  63 0b f6 1c fc e4 9e b0 90 ca 7d c6 90 0f e9 85  c.........}.....
  000001e0  8e 54 db f2 13 68 d7 7e 0e 4c 9d 6a 85 8d 4e 77  .T...h.~.L.j..Nw
  000001f0  b8 25 98 f4 8a 63 31 34 7c 1e 91 15 14 f2 94 dc  .%...c14|.......
  00000200  d2 24 f9 f7 66 79 b9 86 73 43 b1 e1 13 08 78 bc  .$..fy..sC....x.
  00000210  a3 1a f6 53 48 cf c1 99 4e a5 65 b6 ab b0 03 e6  ...SH...N.e.....
  00000220  28 d6 c4 7a 1f 26 cd a1 f3 e6 15 a9 00 00 00 8f  (..z.&..........
  00000230  00 00 00 07 73 73 68 2d 72 73 61 00 00 00 80 c4  ....ssh-rsa.....
  00000240  13 df 45 7f e4 5f 77 6e b0 39 c2 eb d6 88 2f 68  ..E.._wn.9..../h
  00000250  7f d0 5f 78 e6 9d 82 2d 5a a0 10 95 a5 4b 22 2c  .._x...-Z....K",
  00000260  94 4f 34 be 01 55 22 d1 65 aa 3b 4b c0 d9 39 27  .O4..U".e.;K..9'
  00000270  67 db 0b 4b 6c 2b ee 3b a8 71 a8 2a 4b 65 d4 59  g..Kl+.;.q.*Ke.Y
  00000280  39 81 57 93 8e 53 e9 ba c5 e0 82 32 90 88 95 9f  9.W..S.....2....
  00000290  3f 51 0f 01 a8 ca 21 64 e4 b1 db da f2 31 f7 67  ?Q....!d.....1.g
  000002a0  07 d1 2d 55 0d 87 28 ff 7c 5a d8 b7 ac 0d 05 01  ..-U..(.|Z......
  000002b0  fc 13 35 98 de 8d 14 c8 be 7c e2 70 75 8c 22     ..5......|.pu."
Event Log: Host key fingerprint is:
Event Log: ssh-rsa 1024 07:d6:90:67:06:ee:5b:32:e7:a9:34:dc:44:85:21:b9
Outgoing packet #0x3, type 21 / 0x15 (SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS)
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  00 00 00 0c 0a 15 15 16 ce 95 d3 74 ae fc ee 08  ...........t....
Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
Incoming packet #0x3, type 21 / 0x15 (SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS)
Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Outgoing packet #0x4, type 5 / 0x05 (SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST)
  00000000  00 00 00 0c 73 73 68 2d 75 73 65 72 61 75 74 68  ....ssh-userauth
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  55 ad 60 36 bd 9e 96 1b 2a 73 50 e2 5c d4 e5 9d  U.`6....*sP.\...
  00000010  46 33 0f d7 88 24 ad f4 86 51 49 df ee f8 08 78  F3...$...QI....x
  00000020  92 99 91 64 95 49 82 ba 17 1f 79 ab fc a3 8a e0  ...d.I....y.....
  00000030  78 e4 ef a7                                      x...
Incoming raw data at 2015-04-20 11:47:52
  00000000  0e 50 4b 78 de 11 02 d6 b2 41 56 f0 36 5d 45 65  .PKx.....AV.6]Ee
  00000010  a3 94 e5 5d cf c8 d6 22 91 61 c1 39 07 3c ad 26  ...]...".a.9.<.&
  00000020  a6 a2 6e 2b 70 d8 50 df 81 f8 45 ef e4 0b 7d 7b  ..n+p.P...E...}{
  00000030  b2 3f b4 cb                                      .?..
Incoming packet #0x4, type 6 / 0x06 (SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT)
  00000000  00 00 00 0c 73 73 68 2d 75 73 65 72 61 75 74 68  ....ssh-userauth
Outgoing packet #0x5, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
  00000000  00 00 00 06 62 31 36 38 33 36 00 00 00 0e 73 73  ....b16836....ss
  00000010  68 2d 63 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 00 00 00 04  h-connection....
  00000020  6e 6f 6e 65                                      none
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:48:01
  00000000  8c a7 83 49 3b 38 bd cb 92 ae 5f 2f de 46 df 2e  ...I;8...._/.F..
  00000010  67 5a 88 68 4a 6b 0a 79 9c 5b b2 6f d2 75 cf 0c  gZ.hJk.y.[.o.u..
  00000020  e2 0c 3c e2 9a ea 88 8f 06 e2 cf 69 3c f4 ef 32  ..<........i<..2
  00000030  92 70 5f bf 7c f6 93 9e 33 25 97 30 7d fa 1d 2c  .p_.|...3%.0}..,
  00000040  b1 30 00 c4                                      .0..
Incoming raw data at 2015-04-20 11:48:01
  00000000  a4 5b 35 fd e6 87 76 77 74 78 d1 38 13 30 27 c0  .[5...vwtx.8.0'.
  00000010  74 e5 71 6f 51 2c c4 21 ea e7 1d 4b 02 36 cf b9  t.qoQ,.!...K.6..
  00000020  13 9b b1 73 9a c3 61 6b 45 70 d5 d5 02 3c a4 fe  ...s..akEp...<..
  00000030  8a 2f 29 03 b9 2c e4 27 45 7b a6 65 44 d8 64 a7  ./)..,.'E{.eD.d.
  00000040  89 74 f1 0e 16 04 d2 eb e8 18 bb 70 d9 5b 0c 48  .t.........p.[.H
  00000050  18 05 58 bf                                      ..X.
Incoming packet #0x5, type 51 / 0x33 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE)
  00000000  00 00 00 27 70 75 62 6c 69 63 6b 65 79 2c 70 61  ...'publickey,pa
  00000010  73 73 77 6f 72 64 2c 6b 65 79 62 6f 61 72 64 2d  ssword,keyboard-
  00000020  69 6e 74 65 72 61 63 74 69 76 65 00              interactive.
Outgoing packet #0x6, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
  00000000  00 00 00 06 62 31 36 38 33 36 00 00 00 0e 73 73  ....b16836....ss
  00000010  68 2d 63 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 00 00 00 14  h-connection....
  00000020  6b 65 79 62 6f 61 72 64 2d 69 6e 74 65 72 61 63  keyboard-interac
  00000030  74 69 76 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00              tive........
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:48:01
  00000000  02 ec 2c e6 eb 55 fd ea cc d2 1a ed d9 e6 c6 33  ..,..U.........3
  00000010  d6 37 85 61 50 c2 01 ec 6f e7 8b 77 07 90 77 36  .7.aP...o..w..w6
  00000020  8b 9d ad b5 3d 2a 57 d7 7a 5f 31 a9 b9 2e cc ec  ....=*W.z_1.....
  00000030  d0 1c 43 c2 0a 46 e7 27 75 dc 1e 79 13 44 c9 fc  ..C..F.'u..y.D..
  00000040  27 72 6e 7d 96 dc f5 9f 7d b8 8d 42 35 d6 b3 a8  'rn}....}..B5...
  00000050  2f 48 72 dd a3 35 ba 2f 9b 4e 9f 2a d4 d8 d4 a1  /Hr..5./.N.*....
  00000060  ac cc 1c 1a                                      ....
Event Log: Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Incoming raw data at 2015-04-20 11:48:01
  00000000  49 40 7f a5 6a 71 a8 0a 08 ff 60 a2 11 15 a0 46  I@..jq....`....F
  00000010  2c 26 2e 00 df df d8 e3 d4 9b 7d 7c 84 6b d6 f4  ,&........}|.k..
  00000020  49 2c 91 e4 a7 1a 8e 98 c5 cd 21 73 91 a3 74 06  I,........!s..t.
  00000030  4e 37 be 6e 13 63 5f 84 8c 26 0a 30 1e 98 2b d7  N7.n.c_..&.0..+.
  00000040  fc 99 f8 0a 5d a9 cf 6b 1f a7 16 00 cd e3 50 f1  ....]..k......P.
  00000050  74 19 b9 0d                                      t...
Incoming packet #0x6, type 51 / 0x33 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE)
  00000000  00 00 00 27 70 75 62 6c 69 63 6b 65 79 2c 70 61  ...'publickey,pa
  00000010  73 73 77 6f 72 64 2c 6b 65 79 62 6f 61 72 64 2d  ssword,keyboard-
  00000020  69 6e 74 65 72 61 63 74 69 76 65 00              interactive.
Event Log: Server refused keyboard-interactive authentication
Outgoing packet #0x7, type 50 / 0x32 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST)
  00000000  00 00 00 06 62 31 36 38 33 36 00 00 00 0e 73 73  ....b16836....ss
  00000010  68 2d 63 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 00 00 00 08  h-connection....
  00000020  70 61 73 73 77 6f 72 64 00 XX XX XX XX XX XX XX  password.XXXXXXX
  00000030  XX XX XX XX XX XX                                XXXXXX
Outgoing packet #0x8, type 2 / 0x02 (SSH2_MSG_IGNORE)
  00000000  00 00 00 b0 ca 26 a3 b0 cf 79 bd 7e e4 a6 96 03  .....&...y.~....
  00000010  71 a9 fd e2 3e 9c 21 53 0d 80 bb df f5 04 ac e5  q...>.!S........
  00000020  9a a4 14 5c b6 a5 09 7d 99 c0 6c ac 12 bf 06 08  ...\...}..l.....
  00000030  f4 be 6e 14 30 46 f8 86 72 4a 9e 10 d7 6a c7 50  ..n.0F..rJ...j.P
  00000040  70 0a a1 95 99 c9 86 40 3a 99 b0 d8 c0 27 85 89  p......@:....'..
  00000050  2e 83 76 f3 a0 a1 bf 1d cc 3d c8 bf 72 cc ef c3  ..v......=..r...
  00000060  34 5e 21 e9 2f ec 0b cb ce 53 b3 bd 52 83 30 d9  4^!./....S..R.0.
  00000070  96 64 b8 41 64 48 5e 12 6d 91 80 c8 4b 8a b0 ce  .d.AdH^.m...K...
  00000080  7b 06 1d f4 fd b4 f4 c0 87 db 6f c0 fb 47 39 f3  {.........o..G9.
  00000090  c9 ae 47 49 c0 3c 86 ee 21 a7 8c da d5 32 08 50  ..GI.<..!....2.P
  000000a0  fa 98 10 c8 cb 56 f3 ee e6 ac 71 59 ea f7 d0 9c  .....V....qY....
  000000b0  3c 90 cf 8a                                      <...
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:48:06
  00000000  a5 9c b6 82 7f b3 58 04 f9 35 2a e0 fc b3 a6 f7  ......X..5*.....
  00000010  cd 80 f0 45 62 19 b8 52 6c 81 85 7c d6 46 a7 a4  ...Eb..Rl..|.F..
  00000020  f2 99 e7 80 c9 3a e7 28 86 7b 0e b6 9a 03 03 44  .....:.(.{.....D
  00000030  4c 86 38 65 e5 b7 22 0b 2a 2c ad 3d 5c 92 f3 fd  L.8e..".*,.=\...
  00000040  f4 7a d0 bd 80 f3 e0 e3 aa 2b a6 cf 91 04 4b 35  .z.......+....K5
  00000050  92 f6 dc 21 e0 6f 5a 07 0c 57 d6 21 f9 7a d6 a1  ...!.oZ..W.!.z..
  00000060  52 1a 0d 09 43 ed 14 f0 f7 ac 74 07 df c1 4f 7c  R...C.....t...O|
  00000070  d0 57 fe 77 7f 4d a2 af 4e b3 07 70 5a c7 b3 c3  .W.w.M..N..pZ...
  00000080  39 49 60 75 3b 99 8a 13 1f 0a 87 69 fe 65 22 c6  9I`u;......i.e".
  00000090  15 79 6a 14 61 79 39 74 8e 89 7e 1f d1 cb 5f da  .yj.ay9t..~..._.
  000000a0  7f 44 da 7c 57 e7 ee bc 83 d1 09 7a f5 06 ac 5c  .D.|W......z...\
  000000b0  10 0b 42 e8 04 20 e8 52 4a 00 f2 97 8e 49 ff fd  ..B.. .RJ....I..
  000000c0  9d 9e 8a 9f 73 ad 9a ea d5 60 8f e0 14 eb a8 68  ....s....`.....h
  000000d0  0a 5c 5e 52 fa 77 70 b0 3c 82 53 94 2f 3a 14 59  .\^R.wp.<.S./:.Y
  000000e0  4e fb 0c e6 64 22 6f 00 3c 85 b0 42 27 0e 50 fa  N...d"o.<..B'.P.
  000000f0  b4 46 6f 4d 95 5c e4 d2 0c 72 82 3b 00 70 af db  .FoM.\...r.;.p..
  00000100  a3 4c f6 21 c2 11 0b 5e 2f 01 54 d3 2b 53 2c 0b  .L.!...^/.T.+S,.
  00000110  da 58 ef 2f a7 31 b7 ae b4 b6 f7 98 19 5b 3a cb  .X./.1.......[:.
  00000120  e5 d8 6a 41 30 7f a7 39                          ..jA0..9
Event Log: Sent password
Incoming raw data at 2015-04-20 11:48:06
  00000000  da c9 95 80 ac 13 c6 b5 39 fd 27 fe 59 f1 99 96  ........9.'.Y...
  00000010  8f 3a 3d ef 0e fc fc 45 06 df 45 fc 4b 31 87 45  .:=....E..E.K1.E
  00000020  8b 2a 45 ff                                      .*E.
Incoming packet #0x7, type 52 / 0x34 (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS)
Event Log: Access granted
Event Log: Opening session as main channel
Outgoing packet #0x9, type 90 / 0x5a (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN)
  00000000  00 00 00 07 73 65 73 73 69 6f 6e 00 00 01 00 00  ....session.....
  00000010  00 40 00 00 00 40 00                             .@...@.
Outgoing raw data at 2015-04-20 11:48:06
  00000000  6d e8 6d 6f f8 af 6c 48 5e 05 94 c6 08 d8 0d 9f  m.mo..lH^.......
  00000010  0c 57 ca ff 6a c9 26 05 99 21 03 cc 89 2f e3 ba  .W..j.&..!.../..
  00000020  da 7d 93 8c 83 3d 47 44 14 26 46 a1 db f3 16 cb  .}...=GD.&F.....
  00000030  72 1a c4 db ed b2 b4 c9 77 c1 72 b9 03 83 9b 8a  r.......w.r.....
  00000040  ad de 2e 29                                      ...)
Event Log: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

It's quite big and I couldn't post it all so I've cut some of the raw data from the start figuring that it was the stuff at the end that was more important.

Output from netstat -rn:

```
Routing tables
Destination        Gateway           Flags   Refs     Use  If   Exp  Groups
Route tree for Protocol Family 2 (Internet):
default            10.86.0.1         UG      144 731795486 en4      -      -
10.86.0.0          10.86.3.8         UHSb      0         0 en4      -      -   =>
10.86/21           10.86.3.8         U       440 2619407309 en4      -      -
10.86.3.8          127.0.0.1         UGHS     47  74862531 lo0      -      -
10.86.5.34         127.0.0.1         UGHS      0   2162403 lo0      -      -
10.86.5.235        127.0.0.1         UGHS      0    747050 lo0      -      -
10.86.5.237        127.0.0.1         UGHS      0         2 lo0      -      -
10.86.5.238        127.0.0.1         UGHS      0         2 lo0      -      -
10.86.5.239        127.0.0.1         UGHS      0        71 lo0      -      -
10.86.5.246        127.0.0.1         UGHS      0       391 lo0      -      -
10.86.5.248        127.0.0.1         UGHS      0         2 lo0      -      -
10.86.7.255        10.86.3.8         UHSb      0    204022 en4      -      -
127/8              127.0.0.1         U        38  15677457 lo0      -      -

Route tree for Protocol Family 24 (Internet v6):
::1                ::1               UH       12    315282 lo0      -      -
```

Comment: Im I correct in assuming that if you get the password wrong the first time, then the connection remains open, and you get another go?

Comment: Yes. It only drops the connection when you get it right the first time.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the PuTTY Event Log when the failure occurs?

Comment: similar behaviour on AiX in my case was when administrators had 2 default routes by mistake, 'route show' should work without root privilege if you check this possibility.

Comment: Log output added thanks. I tried 'route show' and got permission denied. Can't get in as root so can't do anything about that :(

Comment: @spike Have you checked `/etc/hosts.deny` on the server for your IP and tried manually adding it to `/etc/hosts.allow`?

Comment: An alternative to `route show` might be `netstat -rn`.

Comment: /etc/hosts.deny and /etc/hosts.allow do not exist. Plus, being a corporate network and we're all on dynamic IPs I can only imagine they would be hard to maintain!

Comment: Added output from netstat -rn. Not really sure what I'm looking at there?

Comment: `grep auth /etc/syslog.conf` to see where sshd logs might be going, then see if you're able to read it. that might provide more clues.

Comment: Ran that command and got the following output:  
`#       kern,user,mail,daemon, auth,... (see syslogd(AIX Commands Reference))`  
`*.info;auth.none        /var/adm/messages`  
`auth.info               /var/adm/secure`  

I don't have access to /var/adm/secure but I've had a look through messages. I can't see anything in there that would point to a log on failure. Lots of messages about queued emails and lots that say `syslog: ifconfig -a`.

Comment: sounds like sshd logs are going to /var/adm/secure; it'd be helpful to see those :(